# How do I get a list of the reports available on any given reporting server?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm wanting to be able to input any given report server url and display a list of reports available on that server.

I found this question, and it's useful if I compile the project with a reference to a specific sql server ([How do I get a list of the reports available on a reporting services instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296682/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-reports-available-on-a-reporting-services-instance)).  But (unless I'm just completely missing something which is possible) it doesn't show me how to do what I've stated above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to Web Service URL (note: *not* Report Manager URL). So if your main managing URL is `http://server/Reports` and Web Service URL is `http://server/ReportServer` - open the second one. It will give you raw listing of available items.

Note that this will include reports, datasources, folders etc.

Comment: How likely is it that the source will change from what's generated automatically by the report server?  Do DBAs oft'/ever change the layout?  I don't know if the reporting server allows this or not, but obviously I want to account for it if it's likely to happen.

Comment: Every time u use that link - it will give you current layout. As to how it changes - it depends on your organization policies. Technically a report can be moved to a different folder, deleted, new reports can be added. Usually it outside of DBA domain, but anything can happen.

Answer (score 20):

You could query the `ReportServer` database of your reporting server.

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Catalog
WHERE Type = 2
```

Should give you a list of all of the reports.

Comment: This is definitely helpful but also requires more/different permissions.  I chose the other answer as it specifically meets the requirement of "any given url".

Answer (score 3):

Same as answer above, 
with a use clause added at top 
(in case this helps anyone ..) :

```
Use ReportServer;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Catalog
WHERE Type = 2
Order by Name
```

I noted that select * above contains a field called Content which might be an issue for an export of result to excel .. So I tried a lesser list of columns :

```
Use ReportServer;
SELECT 
  ItemID, 
  Path, 
  Name, 
  ParentID, 
  Type, 
  Description, 
  Hidden, 
  CreatedByID,
  CreationDate,
  ModifiedByID,
  ModifiedDate,
  Parameter
FROM dbo.Catalog
WHERE Type = 2
Order by Name
```

The first answer above didn't seem to work for me .. 
i.e. http://server/ReportServer
(replacing server with my reporting server name ..) 
I get message "The webpage cannot be found" ..
Maybe this answer is version or security settings specific ?