# Search for available reports on server using C#

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I would like to somehow cycle through my Reporting Server and display available reports to the user. Is this possible? 
My Code is as follows (still in development):

```
                ServerReport sr = new ServerReport();
            sr.ReportPath = reportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath;
            sr.ReportServerUrl = new Uri(Path);
            ReportParameterInfoCollection rpc = sr.GetParameters();
            if (rpc.Count > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("New");
            string outputPath = @"C:\Temp\PdfReport.pdf";
            string mimeType;
            string encoding;
            string extension;
            string[] streams;
            Warning[] warnings;
            byte[] pdfBytes= sr.Render("PDF", string.Empty, out mimeType, 
                out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);

            // save the file
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
                fs.Close();
            }
```

Comment: like, is there a way that i could cycle through the files on the server and then filter out the datasets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the ReportingService2010 web service to retrieve all deployed items (data sources, shared data sets and reports) and also to deploy directly to Reporting Services.

Here is just one example of the many methods available:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.listchildren.aspx

The ListChildren method will return all items (as a CatalogItem object) under a folder. If you give it the root folder, it will return everything. You should then be able to determine what item each CatalogItem represents.

Hope that helps,

Ash

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this problem  and would like more information about Ash Shah's answer, see this SO post:
[How do I get a list of the reports available on a reporting services instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3296682/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-the-reports-available-on-a-reporting-services-instance)